# False answer terminating my program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a program that simulates a rock, scissors, paper game and this is my code:

```
weaponsList=['Rock', 'Scissors', 'Paper']
Play1=input('Choose your weapon: ')
if Play1 in weaponsList:
       if True:
            print('You chose '+ Play1)
       if False:
            print('Choose a valid weapon: Rock, Scissors or Paper')
```

If true, the program goes all fine, but if False, it just terminates. It's a simple logic trick, I think, but I just can't see it.

Comment: That's not how `if` statements work. At all. When do you think `if False` will run? Anyways... use `if` and `else`...

Comment: Your given code does not work. The `if True` will *always* execute if enountered and `if False` will *never* execute if encountered. What is your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

```
weaponsList = ['Rock', 'Scissors', 'Paper]
Play1 = input('Choose your weapon: ')
if Play1 in weaponsList:
    print('You chose '+ Play1)
else:
    print('Choose a valid weapon: Rock, Scissors or Paper')
```

if you choose the right weapon, the if statement is True you dont need another if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing how you want to perform your check.

When you check to see if `Play` is *in* `weaponList`, *that* is actually where your check is being made for `True` or `False`. The `if True` and `if False` are *not* behaving the way you think they are. Ultimately, all you need to do is this:

```
weaponsList=['Rock', 'Scissors', 'Paper']
Play1=input('Choose your weapon: ')
if Play1 in weaponsList:
        print('You chose '+ Play1)
else:
        print('Choose a valid weapon: Rock, Scissors or Paper')
```

So, for the above, if your input for `Play1` *is* in `weaponsList`, *that* result will be `True` and you will end up printing the "You chose ..." line.

In the event it is *not* in `weaponsList`, then it will fall to your else statement and print the "Chose a valid weapon:..." line.

An area of improvement to ensure your matching is not unnecessarily strict. Have your list hold only the lowercase words:

```
['rock', 'scissors', 'paper']
```

Then, when you check for containment, just call the `lower` method on your `Play1` string:

```
if Play1.lower() in weaponsList
```

Answer (score 0):

not True or False but if `in` array, your code should be like this

```
weaponsList=['Rock', 'Scissors', 'Paper']
Play1=input('Choose your weapon: ')
if Play1 in weaponsList:
  print('You chose '+ Play1)
else:
  print('Choose a valid weapon: Rock, Scissors or Paper')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with **If statements**. i will show you an example.

```
if condition:
    indentedstatementBlock
```

it's means that If the condition is true, then do the indented statements. So it's happening just when your condition be True.
**So i rewrite if Statements.**

```
if Play1 in weaponsList:
        print('You chose '+ Play1)
else:
    print('Choose a valid weapon: Rock, Scissors or Paper')
```